# Does there exist a subsequence of the $\Sigma_i$ with bounded curvature such that locally converges to $\Sigma$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Let $\Sigma_i$ are smooth complete hypersurfaces in $R^{n+1}$. We assume that $|A_i|\le C$, where $A_i$ are the second fundamental form of $\Sigma_i$, and $C$ is a constant, does there exist a subsequence (still denoted by $\Sigma_i$) and a hypersurface $\Sigma$ such that $\Sigma_i$ locally converges to $\Sigma$.

When $\Sigma_i$ are compact, Ascoli-Arzela theorem tells us that it is true. When $\Sigma_i$ are properly, it is still true. Here's my question：is it still true without properly assumption.

Add:(*Someone may give a counterexample to the above problem, as long as let $\Sigma_i$ is a translation of $\Sigma$ in a certain direction. My question is : covering argument, diagonal argument, Ascoli-Arzela theorem, etc. can still be work without properly assumption*)

My initial question is: Let $\Sigma$ are smooth complete hypersurfaces in $R^{n+1}$(without properly assumption), $x\in \Sigma$'s closure, denoted $\Sigma_r=(\Sigma-x)/r$. For any $R$, assumed that $|A_r|\le C$ on $B_R$. Does there exist a subsequence of $\Sigma_r$'s and a hypersurface $\Sigma'$ such that $\Sigma_r$ locally converges to $\Sigma$.

Comment: What is the definition of properly that you are using here?

Comment: A hypersurface $\Sigma$ is said to be properly if $\Sigma\cap B_R$ is compact for any $R$.

Comment: It suffices to give a counterexample when $n=1$. How about a sequence of spirals that lie outside but approach the unit circle?

Comment: The general question seems unlikely to have a definitive answer if you do not allow for weak versions of convergence. For example one can image a union of infinite planar curves $(\gamma_k \mid k \in \mathbf{N})$ which you 'fold' (with bounded curvature) an increasing number of times, so that $\mathcal{H}^1(\gamma_k \cap B_1) \to \infty$ in the unit ball. Am I correct in assuming that in the 'initial question' you are interested in the case where the radii tend to zero? In this case you should get a positive answer, because for small $r$ the intrinsic and extrinsic balls are comparable.

Comment: Thanks, @LeoMoos,@DeaneYang. Indeed,  I also doubt the correctness of the compactness theorem without properly assumption, it’s just that I can’t tell why.  This kind of compactness theorem has been widely used in geometry, it’s just that I haven’t seen anyone give a formal proof, yes, locally, surfaces can be written as graph, and bounded curvature implies $C^{1,\alpha}$ estimation, by Ascoli-Arzela theorem, diagonal argument, etc., one can get compactness theorem "in mind".  ...

Comment: ...  On the other hand, on the "initial question", taking @DeaneYang 's example, choose $x\in S^1$,  blow-up $c_1$ at x，it is possible to get countless lines. In this case, this is not convergence in the classic sense ( right?).

Comment: I just realised that my comment was not quite accurate, because I misread your question: I overlooked the fact that the blow-up belongs to the closure of $\Sigma$ rather than the surface itself. Regarding your second point, perhaps you could be more specific about the context in which you would like to justify this?

Comment: @LeoMoos Thanks. Let $X:\Sigma\to R^{n+1}$ is a complete (possibly embedded) hypersurface satisfying certain conditions (without properly assumption), I try to prove that $\inf |X|^2\ge c>0$, here is my ieda: if not, let $x_i\in \Sigma$, $x_i\to 0, i\to \infty$, then construct a family of surfaces $\Sigma_i$ (e.g. $\Sigma_i=\Sigma-x_i/r_i, r_i\to 0$), if the comactness theorem holds，we can get $\Sigma_i\to\Sigma'$, then we rule out this possibility in the end. The compactness theorem plays an essential role in this idea. This is why I asked this question.

Comment: I was referring to the following sentence you wrote: 'This kind of compactness theorem has been widely used in geometry, it’s just that I haven’t seen anyone give a formal proof'. Although it's true that these sort of results are commonly used, to my knowledge one is usually given additional hypotheses, local area bounds for example.

Comment: @LeoMoos. Yes, using the bounds on the area (and genus) to get uniform total curvature bounds, then argue as in Choi–Schoen to get bounds on curvature.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: were you interested in *minimal* hypersurfaces all along?

Comment: @LeoMoos No, actually. I'm interested in self-shrinkers, which is very similar to minimal surfaces. Thanks for your constant reply.

Comment: If you have a sequence of pointed immersions $(\varphi_i : \Sigma_i \to R^m,p_j)$ with uniformly bounded derivatives of second fundamental form, then a subsequence will converge in a "Cheeger--Gromov sense" to a pointed immersion $(\varphi : \Sigma\to R^m,p)$. This is spelled out very explicitly here https://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.5697.pdf. You do not need any area estimate. Note that without higher derivatives of curvature, the same fact holds but you just get $C^{1,\alpha}$ convergence.

Comment: Note that self-shrinkers are minimal with respect to the Gaussian metric, so the theory applies verbatim (and you indeed have higher derivative estimates for the second fundamental form).

Comment: @OtisChodosh Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$$c_n(t) = \begin{cases} \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)(1,t)&\text{ if }t \le 0 \\ \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n(1+t)}\right)(\cos t,\sin t) &\text{ if }t \ge 0\end{cases}$$